# How do I authorize Ubuntu to access my Google acct? The "online account" window is black.

Tags: 16.04, online-accounts

When I try to add my Google acct as an external acct, I get a black screen:

[image]

Eventually I get a login pop-up, choose to authorize it, and then go through the same dialog in the "online accounts" window, and come right back to this black screen.

I'm not even sure where to begin troubleshooting.

Comment: I just tried this process on my 16.04 and had no issue with a black screen. Could it be a graphics driver or network issue? But I swear I encountered this issue on a different Ubuntu machine, just can't remember the resolution.

Comment: I briefly see the black background when opening that window, but it then loads the correct web site to login. Do you see a menu with the "Reload" option if you right-click the black part of the window?

Comment: This time around I waited and waited and it eventually loaded.  It takes eons -- like 10-15 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved in 18.04 LTS

So I'm going with "it was a bug and the bug is addressed in an update."